# Rendering Problems on Android Studio: coordinator layout and appbarlayout

Tags: android, android-studio

I just recently installed Android Studio on my Macbook and following an online tutorial online since I'm kind of new to mobile development. However, the guy dictating the tutorial is on a Windows. So the first tutorial was to change the theme. But when I tried doing this I got this error message... Can anyone help? Thank you so much I really appreciate it! :D [Rendering Problem when trying to change theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDTD5.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1' to the dependencies in your build.gradle file.

Please put the correct version. Mine is 23.0.1 at the moment.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input but it already has that line in my build.gradle file. In addition, I have version 23.0.1 as well. Could there be another way to fix it?

Comment: Check if your styles uses Theme.AppCompat theme.

Comment: I made sure I had downloaded the LATEST version of `Build tools` from SDK manager as its not automatic and then I changed my *Project Structure* to use `Build Tools version` (23.0.2) & `Source Compatibility` 1.7 `Target Compatability` 1.7